# Solidify modifier applies uneven thickness,Why?

Tags: solidify-modifier

Why is this so? Especially since I have set the Thickness to Even, this seems unexpected. Thank you.

[image]

By the way, this is my original object:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see if you have doubled any points along that edge?  Sometimes that can cause an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have, but it didn't fix the problem. @common_goldfish

Comment: Can you upload the file?

Comment: Did you apply scale?

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/ab2s8l6ku1tb3g2/upload.blend/file   Here's my file, thank you. @mqbakamqbaka

Comment: Thank you, applying the scale did the trick! @TheJeran

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would apply scale and also check to see if there are double vertices.

I had a similar bug once due to double verts so you can check that by going into: mesh > cleanup > merge by distance ( and ) delete loose.

Sometimes it's a normals thing too! Make sure they're all facing the correct side ( blue ). You can check that with "face orientation" under "show overlays" ( top right with the overlapping circles ).

But it's almost always not applying scale from my experience.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Anytime a modifier doesn't work quite how you were expecting you usually forgot to apply scale. Happens to everyone.