# Solidify not working properly

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, solidify-modifier

i am trying to create a chair, i followed a tutorial for the modeling part, clicked a and then solidify, the problem is that it doesn't follow the chair shape correctly. As you can see, under the chair it remains flat. I'm a newbie on blender and don't know how to solve this problem. [image: here is the chair, i want the solidify tool to give thickness under the chair too]

Comment: Apply the scale in Object mode (Ctrl A)

Comment: Thank you sm it worked

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253469/solidify-modifier-applies-uneven-thickness-why https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data/

Answer (score 0):

Your scale is not 1:1:1, you need to apply the scale in Object mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)